# Can't update Meteor on Windows 8.1 machine

Tags: windows, meteor

When I run 'meteor update', it says that I have the latest version Meteor 0.8.3.  When I specify the release using '--release 0.9.2.2', it says that the version is unknown.

What's going on here?

I tried reinstalling but got the exact same behavior.

Comment: If you want to use the native version of Meteor Windows you're out of luck because the latest stable release is 0.8.3, the maintainer of the Windows port said recently that post 0.9 is working locally on his machine but he needs some more time to polish things. Run a VM :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Meteor does not support Windows out of the box. That means that it has to be ported, which takes some time. So if you want the newest Meteor version as soon as it is released, you can either run a VM with Linux (for example, using [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) or install [Linux alongside Windows](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) on you computer (make sure to back up all data before, though!)

Or you can just wait becuase as saimeunt pointed out, Meteor will be ported to Windows soon.

Answer (score 0):

From March 31, 2015, meteor is supported on Windows
https://www.meteor.com/install